# How to validate sizes of multiple image uploads in CarrierWave uploader

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I have my uploader set up for multiple image uploads like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploaders :avatars, AvatarUploader
end
```

and in view file:

```
<%= form.file_field :files, multiple: true %>
```

The issue is that the result will be in a json string of image_urls.

How do I then validate the size of each individual image i have uploaded?

For example, each of the images should be less then 5.megabytes.

Thank you very much!

EDIT:
This is based on CarrierWave(0.11.0)'s new feature thanks to Gen.

Answer (score 0):

[How to: Validate attachment file size](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Validate-attachment-file-size)

And there is no such thing as mount_uploaders:

[Undefined method `mount_uploaders'](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/1551)